# Sequence call cake php 2 behavior callback function

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I want to know how possible cakephp 2.3.6 execute behavior callback in sequence on one more behavior?

for example, I have three behavior:

- CustomBehavior1
- CustomBehavior2
- CustomBehavior3

and they have beforeFind() callback.

I want to call CustomBehavior1 beforeFind at first then CustomBehavior2, CustomBehavior3 ...

I use this but not working:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'CustomBehavior1',
    'CustomBehavior2',
    'CustomBehavior3'
);
```

their beforeFind call in random now.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is "priority", it can be set on any object, so for behaviors, as well:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#object-callback-priorities